# A question on inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't have much idea about inner product space.

So, plz help me to understand this question;

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with real entries.
>   Define $\langle x,y\rangle _A:=\langle Ax,Ay\rangle, \quad x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $\langle x,y\rangle_A$ defines an inner-product if
>   and only if
>
> (a) Ker A={0}
>    (b) Rank A=n
>    (c) All eigenvalues of are positive.
>    (d) All eigenvalues of are non-negative
>
> More than one option may be true.

Comment: Do you know the properties a binary product must have to be called an inner product?

Comment: Are you saying that it is an inner product iff all of those are satisfied? The first two bullet points are equivalent.

Comment: no its a multiple choice question.

Comment: Also, is $A$ a square matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Is the question to decide which of the four conditions completes the sentence in a mathematically correct way? If so, the first and second statements are equivalent and they do complete the sentence in a correct way. The third bullet is too strong to require (i.e., that will imply that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is an inner product but it is not necessary). The fourth bullet is neither sufficient nor necessary.

In any case, we see that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is bilinear, symmetric and non-negative definite (in the sense that $\langle x,x \rangle_A \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$). The only possible thing that could go wrong is that we could have $\langle x,x\rangle_A = 0$ for some non-zero $x$. However, we know that the standard inner product is positive definite, so this will happen if and only if $Ax = 0$ for some non-zero $x$. That is: $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is not an inner product if and only if $Ax =0$ for some non-zero $x$. Conversely, $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is an inner product iff and only if $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution iff $A$ is invertible. Bullets 1 and 2 are equivalent to $A$ being invertible hence they are equivalent to $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ being an inner product. Bullet 3 implies that $A$ is invertible and thus implies that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is an inner product; however, $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ could still be an inner product if 3 fails. Both invertible and non-invertible matrices can satisfy bullet 4, so this bullet does not imply that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ is an inner product, nor is it implied by $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_A$ being an inner product.